# I am trying to assign value to varibale outside of callback function but it is not assigning value ans shows udefined

Tags: node.js, express

So basically I am writing one program where I am converting values from one currency to another. My function looks like this, I am using OpenExchangeRates API to get value Package doc is [this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-exchange-rates) and fx is a submodule of `OXR` which is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/money)

```js
async function convertToAnotherCurrency(base, toConvert, amountToBeConverted) {
  var convertedValue;
  await oxr.latest(async () => {
    fx.rates = oxr.rates;
    fx.base = oxr.base;
    convertedValue = await fx(amountToBeConverted).from(base).to(toConvert);
    console.log(convertedValue); //this is logging expected response
  });
  console.log(await convertedValue); // this is showing undefined
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong or help me with suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you define fx? Do you have `const fx = require("money");` anywhere? Where is `oxr` defined? Please show all code -- minimal, but reproducible.

Comment: thanks for your willingness to help, Yes I've defined them, that's why code is running if it's not defined it would not let me start the server. that's why I didn't share those lines.

but in future, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I asked not because you I thought you didn't define them, but because their meaning was ambiguous without context. For example, there was no indicator that oxr was the open-exchange-rate module because in your post you said it was the money module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this issue as `latest` method from `open-exchange-rates` is not giving you a promise. Below will solve your issue:

```js
const fx = require("money");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const oxr = require("open-exchange-rates");

const oxrLatestPromisify = promisify(oxr.latest);

oxr.set({ app_id: "your_app_id" });

async function convertToAnotherCurrency(base, toConvert, amountToBeConverted) {
  var convertedValue;

  await oxrLatestPromisify();

  fx.rates = oxr.rates;
  fx.base = oxr.base;

  convertedValue = await fx(amountToBeConverted).from(base).to(toConvert);

  console.log(convertedValue);
}
```